# How to use Nokogiri's xpath and at_xpath methods

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm learning how to use Nokogiri and few questions came to me based on this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

post_agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
post_page = post_agent.get('http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=230708')

puts "\nabsolute path with tbody gives nil"
puts  post_page.parser.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]').xpath('text()').to_s.strip.inspect

puts "\n.at_xpath gives an empty string"
puts post_page.parser.at_xpath("//div[@id='posts']/div/table/tr/td/div[2]").at_xpath('text()').to_s.strip.inspect

puts "\ntwo lines solution with .at_xpath gives an empty string"
rows =   post_page.parser.xpath("//div[@id='posts']/div/table/tr/td/div[2]")
puts rows[0].at_xpath('text()').to_s.strip.inspect


puts
puts "two lines working code"
rows =   post_page.parser.xpath("//div[@id='posts']/div/table/tr/td/div[2]")
puts rows[0].xpath('text()').to_s.strip

puts "\none line working code"
puts post_page.parser.xpath("//div[@id='posts']/div/table/tr/td/div[2]")[0].xpath('text()').to_s.strip

puts "\nanother one line code"
puts post_page.parser.at_xpath("//div[@id='posts']/div/table/tr/td/div[2]").xpath('text()').to_s.strip

puts "\none line code with full path"
puts post_page.parser.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/table/tr/td/div[2]")[0].xpath('text()').to_s.strip
```

- Is it better to use `//` or `/` in XPath? [@AnthonyWJones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982624/using-xpath-how-do-i-select-a-node-based-on-its-text-content-and-value-of-an-att/1982666#1982666) says that "the use of an unprefixed `//`" is not such a good idea.
- I had to remove `tbody` from any working XPath otherwise I got a `nil` result. How is possible to remove an element from the XPath to get things to work?
- Do I have to use `xpath` twice to extract data if not using a full XPath?
- Why can't I make `at_xpath` work to extract data? It works nicely in "[How do I parse an HTML table with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062051/ruby-nokogiri-parsing-html-table-ii/2062210#2062210)". What is the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `//` means every node at every level so it's much more expensive compared to `/`.
2. You can use `*` as a placeholder.
3. No, you can make an XPath query, get the element then call  Nokogiri's `text` method on the node.
4. Sure you can. Have a look at "[What is the absolutely cheapest way to select a child node in Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116629/what-is-the-absolutely-cheapest-way-to-select-a-child-node-in-nokogiri/2118203#2118203)" and my benchmark file. You will see an example of `at_xpath`.

I found you often use the `text()` expression. This is not required using Nokogiri. You can retrieve the node then call the `text` method on the node. It's much less expensive.

Also keep in mind Nokogiri supports CSS selectors. They can be easier if you are working with HTML pages.

Comment: @Simone Carletti: thak you for that. Maybe all my questions come because I do not know how to read documentation on http://nokogiri.org I do not know how to find anything about calling text method on the node. Would it be possible to write more about that. I already find my script bit slow it would be great to make it faster.

Comment: I found that a XPath placeholder is an real xpath expression. So what does it mean to use * as placeholder?

Comment: * means any node. For instance, in `/node/foo/one` and `/node/bar/one`, `/node/*/one` matches both paths.

Comment: could you tell me how to use text method?