# How to read nokogiri.org documentation

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Last week I started to write a script in Ruby. I needed to scrape some data from the web so I was told to use Mechanize and then [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

The Mechanize [documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html)  says:

> Mechanize uses nokogiri to parse html. What does this mean for you? You can treat a mechanize page like an nokogiri object. After you have used Mechanize to navigate to the page that you need to scrape, then scrape it using nokogiri methods.

I know that I can use `xpath` or `at_xpath` because it was part of "[How do I parse an HTML table with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062051/ruby-nokogiri-parsing-html-table-ii/2062210#2062210)" but I do not know the exact syntax of these methods, the difference etc.

I was told in "[how to use nokogiri methods .xpath & .at_xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120012/how-to-use-nokogiri-methods-xpath-atxpath/2120276#2120276)" that

> I often use text() expression. This is not required using Nokogiri. You can retrieve the node then call the text method on the node. It's much less expensive.

I tried to search Nokogiri's documentation but didn't find anything on that.

Is out there somebody who can help me  read Nokogiri's documentation?

I want to know how to use the `text` method instead of `text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what the problem is when reading Nokogiri documentation. A quick search for "nokogiri" on Google returns "nokogiri.org" as the first hit. That is the documentation page.

In Ruby, `text()` is the same as `text` if you are not passing parameters. `text()` is an alias for `inner_text()`, which will

> Get the inner text of all contained Node objects

[Searching nokogiri.org for "text"](http://www.rubydoc.info/search/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri?q=text) will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the things the author means is that the documentation on the site is **not in the standard format/display** as other sites that use rdoc and various methods to show information.  E.G. *it is hard to read*.

To answer, or try to - I've had luck searching around github for projects that use nokogiri and going from there by reading the source.